# C# - SSO Bot Framework error in Teams Desktop and Web

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, botframework, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams

I am working in a tutorial to learn about SSO with C# bot framework.
I followed this tutorial, each step and configuration :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/sbs-bots-with-sso

When I use the "Test in Web chat" option in Azure, it asks for authentication, then I get a code number and it works correctly. It shows the screen for permissions and I get the token.

**Case 1) When I test in Teams web browser version**, I don't get this option displayed:
[image]

**Case 2) When I test in Teams Desktop version**, using the manifest and Load custom application zip file, it shows me the message "We need to ask for additional permissions" (the one that is not being displayed in Teams Web browser version):
[image]

But when I click in "Continue" button, nothing happens.
It is expected to have a browser window open to show the "Permissions requested" page, as it is displayed in the demo in YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJwtUjv3G_o:

[image]

I installed last version of Ms Teams desktop version. Also sign out and sign in again and re-tried, but the "Permissions requested" window is never displayed.
As mentioned, it only works correctly as the tutorial in the Azure "Test in web chat" section. In Teams web browser and Teams desktop I got the scenarios described above.
Would you have any advice or suggestion about it?
Is it possible related to the Teams desktop version? a possible bug in web browser/desktop versions?

Teams version being used:
***"You have Microsoft Teams Version 1.5.00.28567 (64-bit). It was last updated on 02.11.2022."***

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the user is using the application for the first time and user consent is required, the above-mentioned dialog box appears to continue with the consent experience. Could you please share if there is any console error?

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT No error is returned in console. The problem is that the dialog box is not opened, it is not displaying any window. When you click in "Continue" button nothing happens.

Comment: Do you have the correct permissions to grant the application access?

Comment: @AP01 yes, I followed each step of the tutorial link. It works correctly in "Test in Web chat" in Azure, it shows properly access permission window. In Desktop version of teams nothing is displayed.

Comment: We tried to repro the scenario, however in both Teams Web and Desktop client, we are getting the above-mentioned dialog box and can continue with the consent experience. 1.Teams Desktop client: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtLpe.png   https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGL3F.png   2.Teams web client: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDDk4.png  https://i.stack.imgur.com/50P6X.png

Comment: Could you please try using this sample https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-conversation-sso-quickstart and check if it helps? We checked using this sample only.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT I got today's version of code you proposed. I followed each step of the readme and created a separate app registration just for SSO, a different app registration than the one created by the bot, as the "readme" file explains. I It shows me the button about authenticate: https://imgur.com/a/Z2hlac1 but it doesn't show the permissions window. I clicked in "Test connection" in the OAuth connection settings in the chatbot in Azure and it shows correctly the permissions window. What other factor could be causing this error?

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT I see the similar bug in this link https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/oauthprompt-card-does-not-render-inside-of-teams/96ad96cc-4f8b-4cd5-9274-a487bb25a74e but as the last comment I also applied two app registrations but no success. What else can I do?

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT I tried in web browser and mobile version and I get an error about the region in redirect. I was using the value from readme in Authenticate, Redirect URI https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect, it showed that it doesn't match with https://europe.token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect , so I changed to Europe prefix, but still getting the same result, no window permissions displayed. Could it be a region restriction for Teams(EU/US) ? could it a be policy in company Teams? Not sure what next step could be applied to solve the problem.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT I clicked in "Test connection" in the OAuth connection settings in the chatbot in Azure and it shows correctly the permissions window : https://imgur.com/a/0gh1Gk6, but when running the code in Teams desktop, window is not displayed. What other factor could be causing this error?